# What is the expectation of number of rounds to win 3 scisssors-paper-stone in a row?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value

This question stems from the problem of tossing 3 heads in a row for a fair coin, but with draws. Assuming the game is fair, intuitively guessing, is the answer $14\div\frac 23=21$? How to deal with the infinite number of draws?

More generally, if the game is not fair, and the probability of winning, losing and drawing are $x$, $y$ and $1-x-y$ respectively, how would I calculate the expected time to win $n$ games in a row?

Answer (score 3):

Write $m$ for the expected number of games; it is easy to see $m$ is finite.

The expected number of games until the first win is $3$. From this point, one of three things can happen. You can win the next two games (probability $1/9$), finishing in $5$ games (in expectation); you can win the next one game (probability $2/9$); or you can fail to win the next game ($2/3$). In the latter two cases you are back where you started, and expect to play another $m$ games before winning three in a row; you have played $5$ and $4$ games respectively. So
$$m=\frac{1}{9}\times 5+\frac{2}{9}(m+5)+\frac{2}{3}(m+4).$$

Comment: will my answer draw downvotes ?

Comment: This is a simpler approach which I forgot about, and certainly is easier for solving this specific question. In general it should work when the transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ in the corresponding Markov chain (with states $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ are positive precisely when $0\leqslant i<n$ and $j\in\{0,i+1\}$ or when $i=j=n$. I would recommend justifying "The expected number of games until the first win is $3$." It is certainly not a difficult computation, but the result is not immediate to those without a fair amount of experience with probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be i.i.d. sequences of random variables, independent of each other, such that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are uniformly distributed over $\{0,1,2\}$; the $X_n$ represent the player's choices at each time $n$ and the $Y_n$ the opponent's choices. (In this case $0$ denotes "rock," $1$ denotes "paper", and $2$ denotes "scissors.") Let $Z_n$ take values $1$, $0$, and $-1$ as according to when the player wins, draws, or loses, respectively, then we can write
$$
Z_n := \mathsf 1_{\{1,-2\}}(X_n-Y_n) - \mathsf 1_{\{-1,2\}}(X_n-Y_n).
$$
By symmetry, $Z_n$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-1,0,1\}$. Define
$$
\tau = \inf\{n\geqslant 3: Z_n=1, Z_{n-1}=1, Z_{n-2}=1\}.
$$
$\tau$ is the number of games played until the player wins three consecutive games. It has a phase-type distribution, i.e. it is the distribution of the hitting time of the absorbing state in an absorbing Markov chain with finitely many states. It seems that the closed form for $\mathbb P(\tau = k)$, for integers $k\geqslant 3$ is not practical to write explicitly. One can compute the value for a given $k$ by exponentiating a submatrix of the transition matrix of the absorbing Markov chain and left/right-multiplying it by two vectors: see here for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_phase-type_distribution

Fortunately, there is a trick by which we can readily compute the expectation of $\tau$. Consider the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= 1+\frac23\tau_0 + \frac13\tau_1\\
\tau_1 &= 1+\frac23\tau_0 + \frac13\tau_2\\
\tau_2 &= 1+\frac23\tau_0 + \frac13\tau_3\\
\tau_3 &= 0.
\end{align}
Here $\tau_i$ is the expected number of *remaining* games played until winning three consecutively (hence $\tau_3=0$). Solving this system of equations gives
$$
\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= 39\\
\tau_1 &= 36\\
\tau_2 &= 27\\
\tau_3 &= 0.
\end{align}
$$
The quantity we are interested in is of course $\tau_0$, which is $39$. This agrees with the result obtained using the fundamental matrix of the absorbing Markov chain. I've left out the details of modelling this problem as a Markov chain for brevity; it would double or triple the length of the post without lending much more insight into the problem at hand.

If it is unclear as to how I came up with the system of equations to solve the problem, I recommend you construct the appropriate Markov chain and look at the transition probabilities. You should see a clear connection. If it is still not clear, try solving the problem for "number of rounds to win one game" (which would simply have a geometric distribution) and generalizing it to "number of rounds to win $n$ consecutive games," using the Markov chain approach.

As for generalizing to a game with the probability of winning being $p\in(0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}$, one would need only to construct the Markov chain with transition probabilities modified accordingly.

Comment: is my answer worthy of staying in here or will it draw downvotes ?

Comment: @Spectre Your answer doesn't appear to really provide an answer or at least a clear attempt at one, and in fact seems to be making assumptions which don't follow from the question as stated. Without any information on the players' strategy, in the context of probability it makes most sense to assume that choices are made at random (i.e. a uniform distribution over the space of possible choices). Your post seems to be assuming that players are making some type of strategy to increase their chances of winning, which isn't mentioned at all in the question. So I think it is not very helpful.

Comment: thanks, I'll delete it.